# Can you increase volt-ampere (VA) rating of a doorbell chime without issue?

Tags: electrical, wiring, low-voltage, doorbell

I'm looking to replace a 16VAC/10VA doorbell transformer with a 16VAC/30VA one—to accommodate a new video doorbell. I'd like to keep the existing mechanical chime, which is rated 16VAC/10VA.

Will changing out the transformer to have a higher allowed amperage have any effect on the chime? Will it make it louder? Or is that controlled by voltage?

Comment: Do double check that the wiring to the doorbell can take the current you need there. The chime is not the issue here as noted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### TL;DR No Problem

An electrical device draws as much power as it wants, if it can, and no more. For example, if you have a light that is designed for a 120V supply and uses 0.1A of current and 12W of power, it doesn't matter whether that light is connected to a 15A circuit (common) or a 20A circuit (also common) or a 30A or larger circuit. There are *safety* issues with using a larger circuit, because if something goes wrong then a lot more current can flow before a circuit breaker stops it. But the light will work the same on any size circuit, as long as it is 120V (some things can use a wide voltage range, some things can't) and at least 0.1A (12W).

Similarly, on a low-voltage circuit, as long as the total power available (the VA rating of the transformer) is equal to or greater than the power required by all connected devices, they should all work just fine.

Comment: Need to mark this [tag:canonical] for all the "can I replace my transformer with..." questions! (Too bad [that idea](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1762/new-tag-canonical) is being shot down at meta - it's a really good one.)